# Qt 5.5.1/minGW 4.9.2: Linker "cannot find lQt5Core"

Tags: qt, linker-errors

I'm trying to build a helloworld project from source following the book "C++-GUI Programming with Qt4". Inside the folder containing the source file I created a project file ("test.pro") using **qmake -project** and a makefile ("Makefile") using **qmake test.pro**. When I run **mingw32-make** I receive the following error:

> C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-4.9.2-win32-seh-rt_v4-rev4/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lQt5Core
>
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> Makefile.Release:77: recipe for target 'release\test.exe' failed
>
> mingw32-make[1]: * * * [release\test.exe] Error 1
>
> mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Staeng/Documents/artofarithmetic/test'
>
> makefile:34: recipe for target 'release' failed
>
> mingw32-make: * * * [release] Error 2

Someone having a similar problem was told to manually include some Qt libraries into the project file. However, I don't want to have to manually edit the project file whenever I introduce a new library, and as far as my (currently very limited) understanding goes qmake is supposed to do all the nasty work.

I'm on a Windows 8.1 x64 machine using Qt 5.5.1 for minGW and gcc 4.9.2 ("x86_64-win32-seh-rev4, Built by MinGW-W64 project"). Where did I go wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Source file:

```
// test.cpp
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel* label = new QLabel("Hello Qt!");
    label->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Project file:

```
# test.pro
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (3.0) Tue Dec 29 00:58:35 2015
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = test
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
SOURCES += test.cpp
```

Comment: Why do you not use Qt Creator?

Comment: @adlag when I open the test.pro file with Qt Creator and try to build the project I get the error:  release/test.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @adlag It works with Qt Creator when I create a new project from scratch, that's a good start at least.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add "QT += core gui widgets" in test.pro file.